# Custom User Model with UUI PK cant login to admin site in Django 3.0, PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-users, django-3.0

My customer user model looks like this :

```python3
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'login'
```

When I try to login to admin after doing manage.py createsuperuser , it throws the following error :

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/
operator does not exist: integer = uuid
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "login" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "login"....
```

I understand this has to do with PostgreSQL being strongly typed and Django not wanting to assume incoming field type. I want to go around this issue as many customer user tutorials out there specify UUID type primary key and don't seem to run into this problem when the steps ask you to login to admin and test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I had a table named `users` in my database. In my case, `django_admin_log` table had a foreign key relation to `users` table. The foreign key column and the referencing column were not of the same type and that caused the problem.

The foreign key column was `INTEGER` and the referenced column was `UUID`.
Dropping and re-creating `django_admin_log` with the following command worked for me.

```
drop table django_admin_log

py manage.py migrate admin zero --fake
py manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I face the similar issue, my project run for a while and I change `AUTH_USER_MODEL`,  zero and migrate again fix! thanks